# Groovy method call syntax

Tags: java, groovy

A tutorial [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Statements) says:

> Method calls in Groovy can omit the parenthesis if there is at least one parameter and there is no ambiguity.

This works:

```
static method1(def val1)
{
    "Statement.method1 : $val1"
}

def method1retval = method1 30; 
println (method1retval);  //Statement.method1 : 30
```

But when I add another parameter to the method:

```
static method1(def val1, def val2)
{
    "Statement.method1 : $val1 $val2"
}
def method1retval = method1 30 "20";
println (method1retval);
```

It gives error

```
Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static Statements.method1() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [30]
Possible solutions: method1(int, java.lang.String)
```

**Q.** So cant I omit parenthesis when having more than one parameters in method call?

**Q.** Also can we omit parenthesis when calling class constructor?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

the call then is `method1 30, "20"`.  The docs say you can omit ( and ) but not the `,`.  In your case the code would be interpreted as `method1(30)."20"` (do the next call).

As for constructors in general the same rule applies.  But usually they are used with `new` and this does not work.

```
class A {
    A() { println("X") }
    A(x,y) { println([x,y]) }
}

// new A // FAILS
// new A 1,2 FAILS

A.newInstance 1,2 // works
```

The errors around `new` indicate, that a `(` is expected and that they already fail at parsetime. `new` is a keyword and holds special behaviour.

In reality this all comes down to: avoiding the `()` to make code nicer (or shorter, if you code-golf).  It's primary use is for "DSL" where you would just turn code into readable sentences (e.g. `select "*" from "table" where "x>6"` or in grails `static constraints { myval nullable: true, min: 42 }`).

Comment: if you can call it with "no ambiguity", yes.  but with `new ...` neither `new A` or `new A 1`  or `new A 1, 2` work.  if you need this for a DSL consider using a builder.   chained calls with one param each work well with leaving out (), and builders/fluent apis quite match that.

Comment: but `new A 1,"2"` also doesnt work and there is no ambiguity, `1` is `int` and `"2"` is `String`. Getting `Groovy:expecting '(' or '[' after type name to continue new expression`

Comment: well i could argue, that the problem is the possible interpretation of this code as `new(A)(1,"2")`.  but my guess there is, that the keywork `new` has just special behaviour in the language.

Comment: ok so this applies only to method calls not constructor calls

Comment: no.  see my edit.  `newInstance` e.g. works. (well, ok, trickery: calling by another way). it just fails for `new`