# Groovy : excute a class.method in a String

Tags: java, groovy

I have a Groovy class here:

```
Plus.groovy
def add = { int x, int y ->
  return x+y
}
```

How could we use it in Groovy or in Java like 'Plus.add(5,6)' and the result is 11

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Groovy method call syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497791/groovy-method-call-syntax)

Comment: Maybe it's not my case. In my case that use the class.method(parameter) in the same string. Plus.add(5,6)

Comment: I'm struggling to pick out the question here. You need to show what you have, what you tried, and how it failed

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here, are you asking how you would use this method with Groovy? Given the following class definition

```
class Plus {
    def add(def x, def y) {
        return x + y;
    }
}

// assert test
assert 4 == new Plus().add(2, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Use the Binding and GroovyShell.

```
Binding binding = new Binding();
GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(binding);

try {
    Object value = shell
            .evaluate("com.groovy.Plus plus = new com.groovy.Plus (); return plus.add(5,6;");
    System.out.println(value);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("exception : " + e);
}
```